# unable to connect to any network with any method

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I'm still pretty new to linux, but I'm good at searching online. Yet there doesn't seem to be any answer I can find to my issue. I'm running the Lubuntu derivative GalliumOS, and my internet connection went out completely on the computer. Pinging a server results in the error `connect: Network is unreachable`, and pinging a website gives the error `Ping: unknown host`. Removing networks and adding them back to connections does nothing either. rebooting did nothing. I found a [guide for adding networks with `wpa_supplicant`](https://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-connect-to-wpawpa2-wifi-network.html), but I hit a roadblock when I reached the command `sudo wpa_supplicant-B -D wext -i <device name> -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` and received 2 vague errors that meant nothing to me (or the internet), so I couldn't continue. I also used the command `pkill nm-applet` and restarted it, and got the error `(nm-access-point.c:285):nm_access_point_connection_valid: runtime check failed: (ap_ssid != NULL)`. How do I repair this and/or repair the damage I may have done?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the specific errors that you're encountering so we might be able to better help you in troubleshooting your issue. Separately, you mention a "Lubuntu derivative designed for chromebooks." Please provide clarification regarding this OS.

Comment: `uname -a && lsb_release -a` would be good as OS-Info. Also `lspci -knn` has valuable info about your hardware and driver.  I do not own a Chromebook, exists different versions of that device? Dev Nomber. Do you have absolute no internet access, not even by ethernet? If so, write the output of the commands to a textfile using `> output.txt` in conjunction with the commands above. If you use a desktop-version there is normally no need to work with the terminal + wpa_supplicant. This should be done with the Network-Manager. Do you have internet when you boot from the installation-medium?

Comment: @AlexOnLinux the output from `uname` is `Distributor ID:Ubuntu, Discription:GalliumOS 2.1, Release:16.04, Codename:xenial`. the relevant driver is `iwlwifi`, there is no ethernet port on the computer, and Network-Manager is not installed and has a network connection editor instead

Comment: Edit your question and add your info in their  : )  I do not know anything about GalliumOS. If it works like the other distros wifi should work out of the box. If u mess around with `network/interfaces` or `wpa_supplicant.conf` it can happen that the desktop tools (like NetworkManager) stop working properly.  As said, the output of `lspci -knn` would also be good to add. There is some more info about the Wireless hardware. I would google for your wireless chip in conjunction with galliumos and iwlwifi.